# Adding rewrite rule dynamically for search results redirecting to 404 URL

Tags: redirect, urls, wp-redirect, template-redirect

We need the search url structure like the below

**URL** : https://siteurl.com/in/chennai/accountant/

We have already a post url with same structure for single post detail page

**URL** : https://siteurl.com/in/chennai/accountant/ramesh/

We have added coding like below

```
add_action( 'init',  function() {
add_rewrite_rule( 'in/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?pagename=on&wpdocs-pro-category-action=$matches[1]&wpdocs-product-cat-id=$matches[2]', 'top' );   
} );
```

If one is matched another one getting 404 for example if the above code works for search url then the post detail page going to 404 page.

Here are the other codes for beautifying url and redirect url written by us

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $query_vars ) {

    $query_vars[] = 'directory_type';
    $query_vars[]  ='in_cat';
    $query_vars[]  ='in_loc';
    
    return $query_vars;

} );
```

**Rewrite code**

```
function wp_search_url() {

    global $wp_rewrite;

    $type = get_query_var('directory_type');

    $product = get_query_var('in_cat');
    
    $location = get_query_var('in_loc');

    $parent = get_term_by( 'id', $location, 'at_biz_dir-location' );
    
    $category = get_term_by( 'id', $product, 'at_biz_dir-category' );

    if($parent){
        $parent_region = $parent->slug;
    }

    if($category){
        $parent_category = $category->slug;
    }
    
        $inCategory= get_query_var('in_cat');
        $inLocation= get_query_var('in_loc');
        $directoryType= get_query_var('directory_type');
    

    if ( !empty(get_query_var( 'directory_type' ))) {



        if(!session_id()){

            $_SESSION['incategory'] = $inCategory;
            $_SESSION['inlocation'] = $inLocation;
            $_SESSION['directorytype'] = $directoryType;
        
        }else{

            $_SESSION['incategory'] = $inCategory;
            $_SESSION['inlocation'] = $inLocation;
            $_SESSION['directorytype'] = $directoryType;

        }
        
        wp_redirect( home_url()."/on/".$parent_region."/".$parent_category."/");
        
        exit(); 
        
    }else{
            return;
        }
    
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp_search_url' );
```

Please help us to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you re-save/flush permalinks after adding/changing the code? I notice your URLs all have `/in/` but your rewrite rule has `/on` not `/in`

Comment: @TomJNowell  we have done all permalink flush even though we are not getting the correct url also we have changed on to in after that also we are not getting the correct url Thanks for ur comment

Comment: you're also using PHP sessions which don't work on a lot of WordPress hosts, this means your redirects will be unreliable, consider switching to standard cookies instead to store that data ( the redirects also use `/on` instead of `/in` )